# How do I test if a string contains two or more vowels in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I test if a string contains two or more vowels?

I have the following code, but it only tests 2 vowels adjacent to each other. I just want to know if the string contains two or more vowels regardless of where they appear in the string.

```
    if /[aeiouy]{2,}/.match(word)
      puts word
    end
```

Comment: This task is [harder than you would suspect](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909334).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `scan` which returns an array with all the matches:

```
if word.scan(/[aeiou]/).count >= 2
  puts word
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
/[aeiouy].*?[aeiouy]/
```

Answer (score 1):

First some questions:

1. What is a vowel? In your example you have `y`. In my eyes, `y` is no vowel. What's about umlauts?
2. Only small letters or also capitals?

In my example you may adopt the constant `VOWELS` to your definition.

I think the easiest was is to count the vowels with `String#count`.

Below an example with three variants a-c.

You wrote about two vowels, not two different vowels. My solutions a+b works only for two vowels, even it is the same one. Variant c works only, if there are at least two different vowels in the word.

```
VOWELS = 'aeiouyAEIOUY'
%w{
  test 
  teste
  testa
}.each{|word|
   puts 'a: ' + word if word.count(VOWELS) > 1
   puts 'b: ' + word if /[#{VOWELS}].*?[#{VOWELS}]/ =~ word
   puts 'c: ' + word if word.scan(/[#{VOWELS}]/).uniq.count > 1
}
```

---

I made a benchmark. The `count` solution is the fastest.

```
require 'benchmark'
N = 10_000 #Number of Test loops
VOWELS = 'aeiouyAEIOUY'
TESTDATA =     %w{
  test 
  teste
  testa
}

Benchmark.bmbm(10) {|b|

  b.report('count') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|word| word.count(VOWELS) > 1} } }
  b.report('regex') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|word| /[#{VOWELS}].*?[#{VOWELS}]/ =~ word} } }
  b.report('scab') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|word| word =~ /[#{VOWELS}].*?[#{VOWELS}]/ } } }
  b.report('scan/uniq') { N.times { TESTDATA.each{|word| word.scan(/[#{VOWELS}]/).uniq.count > 1 } } }
} #Benchmark
```

Result:

```
Rehearsal ---------------------------------------------
count       0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
regex       0.562000   0.000000   0.562000 (  0.562500)
scab        0.516000   0.000000   0.516000 (  0.515625)
scan/uniq   0.437000   0.000000   0.437000 (  0.437500)
------------------------------------ total: 1.546000sec

                user     system      total        real
count       0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.031250)
regex       0.500000   0.000000   0.500000 (  0.515625)
scab        0.500000   0.000000   0.500000 (  0.500000)
scan/uniq   0.422000   0.000000   0.422000 (  0.437500)
```